# Strange files appear my in Django project

Tags: python, django, file, security, monitoring

I just noticed some strange files inside my django project. Files are named with modules of my app or python modules for instance: datetime, or myapp. File names got no extensions. I dont know if it could happen somehow and its normal or should I rather call security alarm.

Inside files look like imagemagick files. Imagemagick is installed on this server.

Example head of file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Creator: (ImageMagick)
%%Title: (hashlib)
%%CreationDate: (2017-07-11T12:49:23+02:00)
%%BoundingBox: -0 -0 970 907
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 970 907
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait
%%PageOrder: Ascend
%%Pages: 1
%%EndComments

%%BeginDefaults
%%EndDefaults

%%BeginProlog
%
% Display a color image.  The image is displayed in color on
% Postscript viewers or printers that support color, otherwise
% it is displayed as grayscale.
%
```

I tried to open them in AdobeAcrobat but there is message that files are corrupted.

Comment: IMHO, this is not a Django or Python related issue. I suspect a daemon that accidentaly walks the parent directory of your Django project and makse ImageMagick stuff with files. Tag your issue with something more appropriate than "python", "django" to get precise hints and answers. This thread talks about tools that may help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13776/how-to-determine-which-process-is-creating-a-file

Answer (score 0):

If you run `import datetime` or `import myapp` in your (Bash?) shell instead of the Python shell, then this will run `import` from Imagemagick. This could create the files you are seeing.